# how extract data from json in php

Tags: php, mysql, json

how to extract from json

```
{"aaData":[["Hitech Institute","0shoaib0@gmail.com","8149587579","2016-02-04 16:55:37","5"],["Hitech Institute","0shoaib0@gmail.com","8149587579","2016-02-04 16:55:38","6"],["Hitech Institute","0shoaib0@gmail.com","8149587579","2016-02-04 16:55:40","9"],["fdsf","fds","654545","2016-02-08 13:52:40","12"],["fsdf","fsdfsdfds","546","2016-02-08 13:53:51","13"],["hjgh","hg","3123123","2016-02-08 14:35:31","14"]]}


foreach($data->aaData as $row) {
echo $row->aaData[1];   
}
```

Its not working please Help me someone

Comment: Uhm... `json_decode` it first...!?

Comment: Also check: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29308898/3933332

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> php has in-built function json_decode() below is the example

```
<?php
$rs=json_decode($jsonvalue);
print_r($rs);
?>
```

[see php official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

** your question o/p**
[image]

This is my updated code

```
$string="";
$data=json_decode('{"aaData":[["Hitech Institute","0shoaib0@gmail.com","8149587579","2016-02-04 16:55:37","5"],["Hitech Institute","0shoaib0@gmail.com","8149587579","2016-02-04 16:55:38","6"],["Hitech Institute","0shoaib0@gmail.com","8149587579","2016-02-04 16:55:40","9"],["fdsf","fds","654545","2016-02-08 13:52:40","12"],["fsdf","fsdfsdfds","546","2016-02-08 13:53:51","13"],["hjgh","hg","3123123","2016-02-08 14:35:31","14"]]}');
$string.="<table border=1>";
foreach ($data->aaData as $key => $value) {
    $string.="<tr>";
    $string.="<td>";
    $string.="<a href=".'yourpath/'.$value[4].">View</a>";
    $string.="<a href=".'yourpath/'.$value[4].">Edit</a>";
    $string.="<a href=".'yourpath/'.$value[4].">Delete</a>";
    $string.="</td>";
    $string.="</tr>";
}
$string.="</table>";
echo $string;
```

this is o/p you add your bootstrap class and font icons
[image: your table o/p]

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5ikP9.jpg

Comment: how to fetech data like this

Comment: you want to edit,delete and view on basis of unique id

Comment: ya i know but i want to know how do i listing with this code

Comment: when you decode your json it return objets object call with arrow operator and last it use in foreach loop

Comment: welcome bro.........:)

Answer (score 1):

```
$json = '{"aaData":[["Hitech Institute","0shoaib0@gmail.com","8149587579","2016-02-04 16:55:37","5"],["Hitech Institute","0shoaib0@gmail.com","8149587579","2016-02-04 16:55:38","6"],["Hitech Institute","0shoaib0@gmail.com","8149587579","2016-02-04 16:55:40","9"],["fdsf","fds","654545","2016-02-08 13:52:40","12"],["fsdf","fsdfsdfds","546","2016-02-08 13:53:51","13"],["hjgh","hg","3123123","2016-02-08 14:35:31","14"]]}';

$data = json_decode ($json, TRUE);

foreach($data['aaData'] as $row) {
    var_dump ($row);   
}
```

I would use `json_decode` ([here documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)) and then will manage to post the data.

Comment: i want row like this in screenshoot

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5ikP9.jpg

Comment: @shoaibmansuri Then you'll need to write the necessary HTML to do that. We're answering your question here, not doing your work for you (for which we have too little context to begin with).

Comment: i know but give me just more way, in short how to print all data by row

Comment: The info is there in $row, the only think  you have to do is post it with HTML

Answer (score 1):

JSON is not an array, an object, or a data structure. JSON is a text-based serialization format - so a fancy string, but still just a string. Decode it in PHP by using [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

```
$data = json_decode($json);
```

For Example:-

```
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';
var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
```

will output

> object(stdClass)#1 (5) {
>       ["a"] => int(1)
>       ["b"] => int(2)
>       ["c"] => int(3)
>       ["d"] => int(4)
>       ["e"] => int(5) }
>
> array(5) {
>       ["a"] => int(1)
>       ["b"] => int(2)
>       ["c"] => int(3)
>       ["d"] => int(4)
>       ["e"] => int(5) }

More over in your case it will be like

```
$data='{"aaData":[["Hitech Institute","0shoaib0@gmail.com","8149587579","2016-02-04 16:55:37","5"],["Hitech Institute","0shoaib0@gmail.com","8149587579","2016-02-04 16:55:38","6"],["Hitech Institute","0shoaib0@gmail.com","8149587579","2016-02-04 16:55:40","9"],["fdsf","fds","654545","2016-02-08 13:52:40","12"],["fsdf","fsdfsdfds","546","2016-02-08 13:53:51","13"],["hjgh","hg","3123123","2016-02-08 14:35:31","14"]]}';
$yourResult=json_decode($data);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($yourResult);
foreach ($yourResult->aaData as $item) {
//do something with this data
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

PHP foreach loop does't directly work on json data.
You need to decode in array first as following
`$data = json_decode($JSON);`

Check [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: how please , can u do.... for me... please please

Comment: How do you downvote a comment...?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get an array with the information of the JSON you need to do this:

```
$output_array=json_decode($json);
```

After that you can go trough the information inside with

```
foreach ($output_array->aaData as $item) {
    //....do something
}
```

Comment: You're decoding as object, not array...

Comment: You are right. Fixed.